# compare two date in two list with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists, the first list contains a type short date data and the second list contains some data, include a insert date. My question is, how to extract all records in second list which contains the date in first list in `c#` using `Linq`?

```
var listScart = (from ListaAppoScartati in listaTimbratureScartate select new { Data = Convert.ToDateTime(ListaAppoScartati.Data).ToShortDateString() }).Distinct(); ;

List<Obj> listElab = listaTimbratureElaborate.Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Data).ToShortDateString().(listScart)).ToList();

Obj:
Name
Andress
Date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you have something (`date` field) in common between both the list. You can use something as follows,

```
class ObjA
{
   string myDate;
   string something;
}

class ObjB
{
   string myDate;
   string anything;
}

List<ObjA> listA = ...;
List<ObjB> listB = ...;
var common = listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => a.myDate == b.myDate)); //assuming you are joining on myDate field
```

Comment: small precisation, the first list it's a simple list of string contain some data, is not a object.

Comment: or you can even use intersect as `listB.Select(a => a.myDate).Intersect(listA.Select(b => b.myDate))`

Comment: @Silentgrave then you can use something like this, `listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => a == b.myDate.toString()));`

Comment: @SamidhT Nice! But I wonder, which one will be faster. Do you know about performance of `intersect` over simple `where` and `select` clauses? :)